# Flex-box alignment not working in IE

Tags: css, flexbox

I have created a page using flexbox for aligning and it is working fine in chrome and firefox but it is completely gone in IE.Is there a way to make it work in IE10 and IE11.

please check the below code

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header-main">
    <div class="header-flexbox-row">
      <div class="header-first">Left</div>
      <div class="header-second">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-main" ng-repeat="level in list.data.left">
    <div class="content-flexbox-row">
      <div class="content-first padding20">
        <div class="approver-names margin25" ng-repeat="approver in list.data.left[$index]">
          <div class="approver-group">
            <div class="group group-id">{{::approver.GroupId}}</div>
            <div class="group group-name">{{::approver.Name}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="group-image">
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="approver-names">+ ADD SELECTOR</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-second padding20">
        <div class="approver-names">
          <div>I</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-third padding20">
        <div class="approver-names margin25" ng-repeat="endorser in list.data.right[$index]">
          <div class="group-image">
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="approver-group">
            <div class="group group-id">{{::endorser.GroupId}}</div>
            <div class="group group-name">{{::endorser.Name}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="approver-names">+ ADD SELECTOR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please find below the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/Mkfn9AlFyNF5Y3bsECgu?p=preview

Comment: In `.wrapper .content-main`, instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: auto`.

Comment: it looks like Flexbox is only partially supported in IE 11 with known bugs and not at all in IE 10. I always use the site CanIUse.com to double check if certain properties are supported. Definitely checkout the known issues tab there. IE 10 and 11 are old now are they not? With couple of versions of Edge out I would put less stock into it being supported than I would normally unless its a requirement.

Comment: @Michael_B : Thank you so much its working perfectly in IE11.